# Why doesn't drag and drop work in QFileSystemModel internally in my Qt application ?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qfilesystemmodel

I have very simple code, that displays file structure:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QFileSystemModel model;
    QTreeView treeView;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    model.setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());
    ui->treeView->setModel(&model);
    ui->treeView>setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    ui->treeView->setDragEnabled(true);
    ui->treeView->viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);
    ui->treeView->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    ui->treeView->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
    ui->treeView->setAcceptDrops(true);

    ui->tableView->setModel(&model);
}
```

I can select file and drag & drop it directly to folder or on desktop, but when I try to do something internally (move or copy, doesn't matter) it shows this [example - even cursor shows that I can't drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fg6v.jpg)
It seems to me, that I've tried all options, Did I forget something to write or set other option ?

Answer (score 5):

> I have implemented QTreeView-based UI widget with QFileSystemModel as data source and
>   enabled drag and drop for the view but still cannot see the cursor
>   showing it is ready for the "drop" action. What did I miss?

Answering you from experience after peeking at similar code. In order to resolve the item accepting the drop a bit more work needed on model's side:

```
// MyFileSysModel is a child from model class used in your example.
// Mind that specific application drag and drop logic may differ.
// I in fact modified that from QSortFilterProxyModel-type of class
// but that should be similar.
Qt::ItemFlags MyFileSysModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags defaultFlags = QFileSystemModel::flags(index);

    if (!index.isValid())
        return defaultFlags;

    const QFileInfo& fileInfo = this->fileInfo(index);

    // The target
    if (fileInfo.isDir())
    {
        // allowed drop
        return Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags;
    }
    // The source: should be directory (in that case)
    else if (fileInfo.isFile())
    {
        // allowed drag
        return Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | defaultFlags;
    }

    return defaultFlags;
}
```

... and of course we need to use the derived model class now:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MyFileSysModel model; // has virtual function member "flags"
    QTreeView treeView;
};
```